# Paste from Firefox to PHPStorm IDE is not working

Tags: firefox, phpstorm

Paste from Firefox to PHPStorm is not working neither with ctrl+v, nor with left-click+paste. I've tried copying from a new pristine firefox profile to no avail. However copying from gedit or nautilus works fine.

OS is Ubuntu 13.10, `java version "1.8.0-ea"`, PHPStorm version is 7.0. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to fix this?

Use Java 1.7 instead of 1.8 -- it's not stable and final yet.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20594